# Cannot Plot Output of Solve

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, function-construction

I'm trying to plot the output of the following function `t2[x_]` in

```
    n1[x_] := 4 \[Pi]*x + Sin[2 \[Pi] 0.6 x];

    t2[x_] := Solve[4 \[Pi] t + Sin[2 \[Pi] 0.6 t ] - n1[x] == 2 \[Pi] && x < t, t];
```

Now, if I type in a particular value it gives the expected answer:

```
    t2[1]
```

> {{t -> 1.5}}

But I can't figure out how to input `x` as a continuous variable, or even a discrete list. I've also tried plotting `Evaluate[t2[x]]` and `Plot[x /. t2, {x, 0, 2}]` in all combinations I can think of but I just can't get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Rick

Comment: Try `t2[x_] := t /. First @ Solve[4 π t + Sin[2 π 0.6 t ] - n1[x] == 2 π && x < t, t]`.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Have you looked around the site? In particular http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users#answer-18706

Answer (score 2):

`Solve` can't find a closed form solution for this equation. Since it can be solved (numerically) for discrete values, then something like `ListLinePlot[{#, t2[#]} & /@ Range[0, 4, 0.1]]` might do what you want.